Oscillation of vector valued function
Assume we have $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. If $m=1$, the notion of oscillation of $f$ is clear. However, what if $m>1$? What's the definition of the oscillation of the vector valued function $f$ in this case? I was not able to find a proper definition anywhere unfortunately. Thanks for any help in advance!

The definition of oscillation that I know is the one from Spivak: for a bounded function $f:A\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
o(f,a):=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}[M(f,a,\delta)-m(f,a,\delta)],
\end{align}
where, letting $B(a,\delta)$ be the open ball in $\Bbb{R}^n$ of radius $\delta$ and center $a$,
\begin{align}
M(f,a,\delta):=\sup_{x\in A\cap B(a,\delta)}f(x),\quad\text{and}\quad m(f,a,\delta):=\inf_{x\in A\cap B(a,\delta)}f(x).
\end{align}
But, we also have (exercise)
\begin{align}
M(f,a,\delta)-m(f,a,\delta)&=\sup_{x,y\in A\cap B(a,\delta)}|f(x)-f(y)|,
\end{align}
and thus the oscillation equals
\begin{align}
o(f,a)&=\lim\limits_{\delta\to 0^+}\sup_{x,y\in A\cap B(a,\delta)}|f(x)-f(y)|.
\end{align}
With that preliminary observation out of the way, we can generalize the definition immediately as follows:

Definition.
Let $X,Y$ be (non-empty) metric spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a map, and $a\in X$ a given point. We define the oscillation of $f$ at $a$ to be
\begin{align}
o(f,a):=\lim\limits_{\delta\to 0^+}\sup_{x,y\in B(a,\delta)}d_Y(f(x),f(y))\in [0,\infty],
\end{align}
where $B(a,\delta)=\{x\in X\,:\, d_X(x,a)<\delta\}$.

First, we should remark that the supremum is a (weakly) decreasing function of $\delta$ since we’re taking supremums over smaller sets; and thus the $\lim\limits_{\delta\to 0^+}$ exists (it equals the infimum over $\delta$). With this definition, we again have the desired theorems that $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $a$ if and only if $o(f,a)<\infty$, and that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $o(f,a)=0$.
Now, you can obviously apply this to $X=\Bbb{R}^n,Y=\Bbb{R}^m$ with any of their metrics.
